# How to recover data stored in file format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I had a ton of photos on my laptop I transferred from my phone. I tried to sort the photos as 'faceless pictures' and 'face pictures' by using python (openCV cascade classifier). I made two folders in my D: drive: 'Face pics' and 'Faceless pics'. But in the destination path in my code, I mistakenly wrote the wrong address. Since the destination folder didn't exist in the address I typed, I saw that my photos were saved in File format in the destination I previously inputted. I don't know what a 'File' format is and how to work with it. I have attached a picture to better explain my conundrum. I want to recover the photos, if possible. Any advice is appreciated.
Below is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shutil

source = 'D:\\User\\Pictures\\'
dest1 = 'D:\\User\\Faceless pics\\' 
dest2 = 'D:\\User\\Face pictures\\' #Here, by mistake, I used 'D:\\User\\Face pics\\'. I should have used pictures instead of pics. The code did not make a new folder; instead it dumped all the data into a single file whose type is 'File' and not 'Text' or 'Folder'

sourcedirs = os.listdir(source)[:-3]

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

for x in sourcedirs:
    for y in os.listdir(source + x):
        if y[-3:]=='JPG':
            style = Image.open(source + x + '\\' + y)
            style = np.asarray(style)
            plt.imshow(style)
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(style, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
                gray,
                scaleFactor=1.1,
                minNeighbors=5,
                minSize=(10, 10),
                flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
            )
            if len(faces)>0:
                shutil.move(source + x + '\\' + y, dest2)
            else:
                shutil.move(source + x + '\\' + y, dest1)
```

[The picture is the properties tab of the file from which I want to recover my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKwGr.jpg)

Comment: Try to change extension of file to `jpg`

Comment: You aren't changing the format of your file anywhere. Windows just reports what the *extension implies*, you've (unhelpfully) blocked out the name of the path you saved it as, but I assume you simply dropped the extension, so Windows reports "File". Extensions are arbitrary, adding an extension doesn't magically change the format of your file, they are just parts of the path/name of the file. It's all just bytes at the end of the day. Just re-name the file with the correct extension and windows will probably recognize it.

Comment: This one file whose picture I attached probably contains more than 10 photos. If I change its extension and hope that windows recognizes it, will I get all my photos back?

Comment: You moved all of the pictures to *the same filename*.  Each one overwrote the previous picture.  Changing the extension will get the last picture back, all the rest are gone.